# mysqli - order by name I'm searching

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a database full of names. And I want to search all the names with `$name` in it. However I want the people that have `$name` as first name to appear first.

For example `$name = John`.

And my results are:

1. Alex John Smith
2. Andrew Michael John
3. John Case
4. John Doe

I want them like (results that have it on first name, results that have it on last name, other results):

1. John Case
2. John Doe
3. Andrew Michael John
4. Alex John Smith

   ```
   $name = $_POST['text_search'];

   $sql = <<<SQL
           SELECT *
           FROM `teachers`
           WHERE `name` LIKE '%{$name}%' ORDER BY `name` ....
   SQL;
   ```

How can I order them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can order in PHP (see @siniradam's answer) ... or you can order in SQL directly:

If you want them in the original order (but those with first name first)

```
  SELECT `name`
    FROM `teachers`
    WHERE `name` LIKE '{$name}%' 

  UNION

  SELECT `name`
    FROM `teachers`
    WHERE `name` LIKE '%{$name}%' ORDER BY `name`
    AND   `name` NOT LIKE '{$name}%'
```

If you want them ordered alphabetically WITHIN 2 subsets:

```
  SELECT `name`, 0 `is_not_first`
    FROM `teachers`
    WHERE `name` LIKE '{$name}%' 

  UNION

  SELECT `name`, 0 `is_not_first`
    FROM `teachers`
    WHERE `name` LIKE '%{$name}%' ORDER BY `name`
    AND   `name` NOT LIKE '{$name}%' 

  ORDER BY `is_not_first`, `name`
```

Caveat - if the table is VERY large, this approach in SQL is slower than PHP-only approach since it basically queries the table twice. On smaller tables it's just as good, however.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this might be work for you.

```
$q = "John";
$result = array(
    "Alex John Smith",
    "Andrew Michael John",
    "John Case",
    "John Doe"
);

function cmp($a, $b){
    GLOBAL $q;
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return (strpos($a, $q) < strpos($b, $q)) ? -1 : 1;
}

print_r($result);
usort($result, "cmp");
print_r($result);
```

here is the result;

```
Array
(
    [0] => Alex John Smith
    [1] => Andrew Michael John
    [2] => John Case
    [3] => John Doe
)
Array
(
    [0] => John Case
    [1] => John Doe
    [2] => Alex John Smith
    [3] => Andrew Michael John
)
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not really sure, but try this: add % symbol only to one side of $name

```
$sql = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT * FROM teachers WHERE name LIKE '.$name.'% ORDER BY name');
```

UPD. Since i am unable to comment yet. Jan Fickos' answer is not correct. It worked because in your example there is no first name that start from greater letter than "J". And also, it is in opposite alphabetical order.

Comment: This isn't any better that Jan's answer - you won't get the names that don't have the search term in the middle.